# Proving that the sequence $1, \frac12, \frac{1/2}{3/4}, \cdots$ converges to $\frac{\sqrt 2}2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product, continued-fractions

I saw this on a Facebook page:
\begin{align*}
1, \qquad \frac12,\qquad\frac{\frac12}{\frac34}, \qquad\frac{\frac{\frac12}{\frac34}}{\frac{\frac56}{\frac78}},\qquad \dots\to \frac{\sqrt{2}}2.
\end{align*}
The $n$-th term is the combination of $2^n$ consecutive integers from $1$ to $2^n$.

> **Question:** How to prove this in a both **rigorous** and **easy** way?

---

**1st attempt**

Let $\{a_n\}$ be the sequence. We try to "simplify" $a_n$ as the form $\dfrac{1\cdot4\cdot6\cdot7\cdots}{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot8\cdots}$, as simple fraction, to find the pattern in which some integers are numerators and others are denominators.

Let $f: \Bbb N \mapsto \Bbb Z$ such that 
\begin{align*}
a_n=\prod_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}k^{(-1)^{f(k)}}.\tag{*}
\end{align*}
However, it seems hard to find the expression / recurrence formula for $f$ and show it converges to $\dfrac{\sqrt2}2$.

---

**2nd attempt**

Again we let $\{a_n\}$ be the sequence. Consider the continued fraction:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt2=1+\underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{\mathrm K}} ~ \frac{1}{2}=1+\cfrac1{2+\cfrac1{2+\cfrac1{2+\cfrac1{\ddots}}}}.
\end{align*}
Then, we define
\begin{align*}
b_m=\frac12\left(1+\underset{i=1}{\overset{m}{\mathrm K}} ~ \frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac12+\frac12\cdot\cfrac1{2+\cfrac1{\ddots+\cfrac1{2}}}.
\end{align*}
Obviously $b_m$ converges to $\dfrac{\sqrt2}2$. Then we just need to show that $a_n$ is between $b_m$ and $b_{m+1}$ for big $m$ and $n$ ( $m$ depends on $n$), which seems complicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tall fraction puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29234/tall-fraction-puzzle). There's also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924601/what-is-cdots-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16).